# Entity Framework This property descriptor does not support the SetValue

Tags: entity-framework

below are my entities which i have created using entity frame work.

**retailer**
id 
name
childs(navigation)

**generated database schema**

[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] nvarchar NOT NULL

**childern** 
id 
name
RETAILER(navigation)

**generated database schema**

[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] nvarchar NOT NULL
[Retailer_Id] [int] NOT NULL,

As you can see in the above model the relationship is 1 retailer can have 0 or 1 child. my problem is when i create a new child and set the retailer navigation property of it to a retailer entity it throws the following exception.how do i solve it

> Error while setting property
>   'retailer': 'This property descriptor
>   does not support the SetValue
>   method.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Retailer navigation property have its Setter property set to Public?